# Google Map user current location to more than 1 destination

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

i tried myself but not get the solution. i get the user current location and map to single destination giving destination as input but not get to draw map to locations more than one latitude and longitude stored in database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this through Google's Directions API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Go through this, you will find everything about Google Maps API.